# git add to .gitignore and keep files

Tags: git

At work we setup a git repo to manage the current site. However we don't want all the files so we added some to the .gitignore right away. However, there are still some files that got into the repo we want removed from the repo, but kept on the server.

The thing is if I add it to the .gitignore it does not remove it from the repo. I've read several similar questions on here. I am worried if I do this wrong I could delete thousands of images from our server.

So how do I add it to the .gitignore, remove the files from tracking in the repo, without deleting them from the server.

```
git rm --cached file
```

seems like it would delete the file or am I wrong?

Comment: these sorts of things can be very easily tested by creating a new repository and trying them out.

Answer (score 2):

You answered the question yourself, my friend.

`git rm --cached file` would remove  from version control, while keeping it in the working repository.